# How to find and fix problems with ChangeDetection in AngularDart5?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

Our project is split in several small projects and a lot of components.
Today we found a problem where the functions used within a template are being executed several times nonstop.
This lead us to believe that one, or many, of our components is messing up the change detection.

```
<div>{{ myFunc(myObject) }}</div>
<!-- it is even worse if the above template is encapsulated by a *ngFor -->

...

class SomeComponent {
 myFunc(var someVar) {
   print('Hello!'); // Hello is being repeatadly print
 } 
}
```

I would like to know how we can analise the generated code or put some prints() in strategic places that can lead us to find the piece of code or the component that is messing the angular tick.

Angular5-11, dart-dev-59 and DDC.

Comment: It's probably just `<div>{{ myFunc(myObject) }}</div>`. Binding to functions is usually a bad idea in Angular. The function will be called every time change detection runs. With the default change detection strategy, this will be quite frequently. With `OnPush` you can reduce that, but binding to functions should still be done with care.

Comment: my problem is that Hello is being print too many times. When in a ngFor, it freezes the screen a little. It looks very weird

Comment: Too many times in relation to what? It's expected to be called often. If you bind to a function you need to make it super efficient (shouldn't do any work). Printing to the console is expensive. It's better to store the values in a collection and access the collection to get the value.

Comment: my function was really simple, it was just something like "someFunction(var obj) => obj == mainObject ? 'ok' : 'remove';". That is why I think there is something wrong that is messing up with change detection. How to find this out (what is messing with change detection) would be a very nice article in medium and would help a lot.

Comment: I don't think something is messing. That simple function (without `print()`) shouldn't cause performance issues thougj. If you have `(mousemove)="foo()"`, then change detection will run every time the mouse moves a bit and change detection will call `someFunction()` for every element in `ngFor` every time.

Comment: What happened was this: I added a transclusion (ngTemplateOutlet) and it suddenly got very slow. When the ngFor had 2 items and had to transclude two times, it would freeze the screen a little. In the button inside the transcluded template there was something like: [icon]="obj == mainObject ? 'ok' : 'remove'". Once I removed this attribute, it got "fast" again. For testing purpose, I added a function that would do the same thing as the inline property and added the print() to check how many times it was being called. That is how I realized that it was being executed too many times.

Comment: I guess there is an event binding like mentioned before that fires very often. I'd also switch to `OnPush` everywhere if you haven't already to be more in control about change detection.

Comment: we have several components that use AbstractControl to update values and such. It could be also be it, right? About OnPush: I will study about it right now.

Comment: I don't understand why you think AbstractControl might be related.

Comment: because it has updateValue() that I guess can tickle the change detection or sort of